# Fuzzy Membership producing narrow output

Tags: qgis, arcgis-pro, fuzzy-logic

I have a rasterized road layer, from which I have calculated an euclidean distance raster extending up to 15000m.[image]

Now, I want to apply fuzzy membership to this Euclidean distance raster using a Gaussian function such that distances at 7500m are most preferred (assigned a value of 1) and distances greater than or less than that are progressively less suitable. I have applied the Fuzzy membership operation both in ArcGIS Pro and QGIS using `Gaussian` with parameters `midpoint = 7500` and `spread = 0.1` the output I am getting is as follows:
[image]

I also have a water proximity raster which I am trying to fuzzify using `Near` (`midpoint = 500, spread=0.1`. Here is the original euclidean distance raster followed by the Fuzzy output:
[image]
[image]

The outputs shown here are from ArcGIS Pro, but QGIS results are also similar. As you can see, I am only getting a very narrow band of acceptable values and no gradient. Outputs change only slightly on changing parameters. Where am I going wrong?

Data:
Source: [Ottawa Open Data](https://open.ottawa.ca/)

Reprojected to UTM Zone 18N

Subset of only Arterial roads

Answer (score 1):

Although the functions and the default values suggest that the raster can have any continuous value, I found the following statement in the [ArcGIS documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/fuzzy-membership.htm) (bold by author):

> This tool does not scale categorical data. To include categorical data into fuzzy overlay analysis, a preprocessing step is necessary. You can create a model or run the following geoprocessing tools. First, use the Reclassify tool to provide a new range of values (for example, 1 to 100). **Then Divide the result by a factor (for example, by 100) to normalize the output values to be between 0.0 and 1.0.**

Thus, I used raster calculator to normalized my road proximity raster by dividing by 15000 and then ran the tool. The output is now as expected:

[image]

The above explanation is for QGIS, but my guess is that the same process will work in ArcGIS too.